# POST the data from a modal form of bootstrap: What am I missing?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Ask Question

- No.1 for booking in our surroundings
- No hidden costs
- Attractive offers with price advantage

Name
                                                        
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        Email address
                                                        
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        Question

```
                            </footer>
```